# Помогите, ошибка в методе Next(), Random

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, char

Я не могу понять почему этот метод не генерирует рандомное число в заданном диапазоне, хотя метод CharToInt() работает исправно так, вот выдает ошибку что первый ArgumentOutOfRange параметр в методе Next, класса рандом больше второго хотя я всё правильно передал дальше в методе Main.
Код:

```cs
public static class Program
    {
        
       static string Generator(char first, char lengthOfArray, int userLength){
        
        int CharToInt(char i){
            return i + '0';

        }
        
            string [] array = new string[userLength];
            Random random = new Random();
            
            int rnd = random.Next(CharToInt(first), CharToInt(lengthOfArray));
            
            for(char i = first; i < lengthOfArray; i++){
                 array[i] = i.ToString();
            }
            string value = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < userLength; i++){
            value += array[rnd];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            return value;
            
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            
        string str = Generator('a', 'Z', 10);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        
        
      
            
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Опечатка `return i - '0';`

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4):

```
static string Generator(char first, char lengthOfArray, int userLength)
...
        int rnd = random.Next(CharToInt(first), CharToInt(lengthOfArray));
...
string str = Generator('a', 'Z', 10);
```

Таким образом у вас `random.Next` вызывается с такими параметрами:

```
random.Next(CharToInt('a'), CharToInt('Z'));
```

Или, что тоже самое (если исправить функцию `CharToInt` согласно комментарию aepot):

```
random.Next(49, 42); // первый аргумент больше второго - вот и ошибка
```

В таблице символов сначала идут заглавные буквы и только потом строчные, поэтому у символа `'a'` код **больше**, чем у `'Z'`.

Отдельно непонятно, почему у этих двух параметров функции именно такие названия, не согласованные между собой. Логично было бы назвать второй параметр, например, `last` тогда, если первый называется `first`. Либо вы вообще забыли ввести параметр для второй границы рандома и используете вместо него переменную, которая предназначена для чего-то другого.

P.S. `CharToInt` у вас не правильно считается, как правильно заметил aepot, но это не влияет на мои выводы.